# R best practices for functions - new function or overload?

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R that I'd like to be able to use on both data.frames and data.tables.  I'm unsure if the best way to do so is to create 2 separate functions or if I should use an `if` statement in the function to handle different types of inputs.

For instance:

```
 myFunction <- function(x){
  if(inherits(x, 'data.frame')){
    return(dim(x))
  }
  if(inherits(x, 'data.table')){
    return(dim(x))
  }
  else{return(NA)}
 }
```

Comment: Probably most people would make two S3 methods, one for each. Separately, typically `class(x) == "foo"` isn't a great idea, people will typically use `inherits` to check S3 class membership.

Comment: For clarity, I suggest there should be *three* functions, not two: `myFunction.default <- function(x) NA`, as well as `myFunction.data.frame` and `myFunction.data.table`.

Comment: To expand on @joran's comment: `class(mtcars)` is length 1, but `class(dplyr::tbl_df(mtcars))` is length 3 despite being (for other intents/purposes) still a `data.frame`, so your comparison will complain (and not work as expected). Ergo `inherits(x, "data.frame")`.

Comment: Since `data.table` objects generally inherit from `data.frame`, your current code will never execute the `data.table` method.  Use @joran's suggestion, and make two S3 methods.  R will get the inheritance right.

Comment: Look at Hadley's guide to S3 for more understanding on writing methods: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html